# Producing a confusion matrix with cross_validate

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to figure out how to produce a confusion matrix with cross_validate. I'm able to print out the scores with the code I have so far.

```
# Instantiating model
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()

#Scores
scoring = {'accuracy' : make_scorer(accuracy_score), 
           'precision' : make_scorer(precision_score),
           'recall' : make_scorer(recall_score), 
           'f1_score' : make_scorer(f1_score)}

# 10-fold cross validation
scores = cross_validate(model, X, y, cv=10, scoring=scoring)

print("Accuracy (Testing):  %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores['test_accuracy'].mean(), scores['test_accuracy'].std() * 2))
print("Precision (Testing):  %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores['test_precision'].mean(), scores['test_precision'].std() * 2))
print("Recall (Testing):  %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores['test_recall'].mean(), scores['test_recall'].std() * 2))
print("F1-Score (Testing):  %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores['test_f1_score'].mean(), scores['test_f1_score'].std() * 2))
```

But I'm trying to get that data into a confusion matrix. I'm able to make a confusion matrix by using cross_val_predict -

```
y_train_pred = cross_val_predict(model, X, y, cv=10)
confusion_matrix(y, y_train_pred)
```

Which is great, but since it's doing it's own cross validation, the results won't match up. I'm just looking for a way to produce both with matching results.

Any help or pointers would be great. Thanks!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/22404668/10495893, https://stackoverflow.com/q/9734403/10495893

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is **you can't.**

The idea of Confusion Matrix is evaluate one data using one trained model. And the result is a matrix, not a score like for example accuracy. So you can't calculate the mean or something similar. `cross_val_score` as name suggests, works only on **scores**. Confusion matrix is not a score, it is a kind of summary of what happened during evaluation.

`cross_val_predict` is quiet similar on what are you looking for. This function will split data in K parts. Each part will be tested with the model you obtained with the other parts of the data. All the tested sample will be merged. But be careful with this function:
*"Passing these predictions into an evaluation metric **may not be a valid way to measure generalization performance.** Results can differ from cross_validate and cross_val_score unless all tests sets have equal size and the metric decomposes over samples."*

Answer (score 5):

I think the nicest approach would be to define the confusion matrix as a scorer, instead or in addition to the other ones you've defined.  Luckily, this is an example in the User Guide; see the third bullet [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#using-multiple-metric-evaluation):

```py
def confusion_matrix_scorer(clf, X, y):
    y_pred = clf.predict(X)
    cm = confusion_matrix(y, y_pred)
    return {'tn': cm[0, 0], 'fp': cm[0, 1],
            'fn': cm[1, 0], 'tp': cm[1, 1]}
cv_results = cross_validate(svm, X, y, cv=5,
                            scoring=confusion_matrix_scorer)
```

Then `cv_results['test_tp']` (etc.) is a list of, for each fold, the number of true positives.  Now you can aggregate the confusion matrices however is most appropriate for you.

---

Another approach came to mind first, and I'll add it here in case it's useful for understanding how sklearn deals with things.  But I definitely think the first approach is better.

You can set `return_estimator` in `cross_validate`, in which case the returned dictionary has a key `estimator` with value the list of fitted models.  You still need to be able to find the corresponding test folds though.  For that, you can define your `cv` object manually (e.g. `cv = StratifiedKFold(10)` and `cross_validate(..., cv=cv)`; then `cv` will still contain the relevant data for making the splits.  So you can use the fitted estimators to score the appropriate test fold, generating confusion matrices.  Or you can use `cross_val_predict(..., cv=cv)`, but at that point you repeat the fitting, so you probably should just skip `cross_validate` and do the loop yourself.